# How to show selected option in select tag of html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using a select tag from html to show some list. Now when I select one of the option from select tag, I want to load the form again and by the selected option I am running another query and showing the values of another query in another select tag.

Its working properly after selecting any option I am posting a type from which I am getting another data in another select tag, but when I click suppose option TSgt and the form reloads with the TSgt type data, but the option selected in select tag shows as MSgt which is not the one I selected.

If I don't check if the $type is set in _POST array and just show the select tag without an select value like follow :

```
<option value="1">SSgt</option> 
<option value="2">TSgt</option> 
<option value="3">MSgt</option>
```

Then, default selected value shows SSgt,I want to show the value in select tag which user has selected.

```
       <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MCQ Questions</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=174.75.54;dbname=handbook', 'airman', 'airman'); 

    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $question = $_SESSION["question"];
    $optionA = $_SESSION["opt1"];
    $optionB = $_SESSION["opt2"];
    $optionC = $_SESSION["opt3"];
    $optionD = $_SESSION["opt4"];
    $ans = $_SESSION["ans"];
    $chapter = $_SESSION["chapter"];
?>

<form method="post" action="mcq.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="text"> <br><br>
Select question type : 

<select name="type" id="type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 

<?php if(isset($_POST['type']))
{ ?>
<option value="1"  selected=<?=($type==1?"checked":"");?>>SSgt</option> 

<option value="2"  selected=<?=($type==2?"checked":"");?>>TSgt</option> 
<option value="3" selected=<?=($type==3?"checked":"");?>>MSgt</option> 
</select>
<?php
}
    else 
    {
    ?>
    <option value="1">SSgt</option> 
<option value="2">TSgt</option> 
<option value="3">MSgt</option> 
</select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

<br><br>
<?php if(isset($optionA))
{ ?>
<p> Enter options :</p>
Enter option A : <input name="opt1" type="text" value = "<?php echo $optionA?>"</input> <br><br>

<?php
}
else{
?>
<p> Enter options :</p>
Enter option A : <input name="opt1" type="text"> <br><br>
<?php   
}
?>

Enter option B : <input name="opt2" type="text"> <br><br>
Enter option C : <input name="opt3" type="text"> <br><br>
Enter option D : <input name="opt4" type="text"> <br><br>

Select correct answer :

<select name="ans" id="type"> 

<option value="A">A</option> 
<option value="B">B</option> 
<option value="C">C</option> 
<option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<br><br>

Select Chapter :


<select name="chapters" id="chapters"> 

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters where type = :type"); 
    $stmt->bindParam("type", $type);
$stmt->execute(); 
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(count($results > 0)){ 
foreach($results as $row):?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></option> 
<?php 
endforeach; 
}else{?> 

<option value="0">No data found</option> 
<?php 
} 

}

else{

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM chapters where type = 1"); 

$stmt->execute(); 
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(count($results > 0)){ 
foreach($results as $row):?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></option> 
<?php 
endforeach; 
}else{?> 

<option value="0">No data found</option> 
<?php 
} 
}
?> 

</select> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value = "Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php

// escape post variables
$question = $_POST['question'];
$option1 = $_POST['opt1'];
$option2 = $_POST['opt2'];
$option3 = $_POST['opt3'];
$option4 = $_POST['opt4'];
$ans = $_POST['ans'];
$chapter = $_POST['chapters']; 


if(!empty($ans) and !empty($question) and !empty($option1) and !empty($option2) and !empty($option3) and !empty($option4) and !empty($type) and !empty($chapter))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer,type,chapterId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array($question, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4, $ans,$type,$chapter));

if ($dbh->lastInsertId())
{   
    echo 'Question submitted.';

    echo '<a href="mcq.php">Upload another question.</a>';
    session_destroy();
}
else
{
    echo 'Question could not submit.';
}

}

else{

    $_SESSION["question"] = $question;
    $_SESSION["chapter"] = $chapter;
    $_SESSION["ans"] = $ans;
    $_SESSION["opt1"] = $option1;
    $_SESSION["opt2"] = $option2;
    $_SESSION["opt3"] = $option3;
    $_SESSION["opt4"] = $option4;

    echo 'Fill all fields.';
}

?>
```

I dont know what is going wrong here. Can anyone help me out please?

Thank you.

Comment: for select its "selected" not "checked"...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected=checked` is wrong. `selected` is enough.

The syntax is `<option value="1" selected>SSgt</option>`

Change the code to

```
<option value="1"  <?php echo($type==1?"selected":"");?>>SSgt</option> 

<option value="2"  <?php echo($type==2?"selected":"");?>>TSgt</option> 
<option value="3" <?php echo($type==3?"selected":"");?>>MSgt</option>
```

Comment: Why not flag as typo?

Comment: I think it is not a typo. He adding `selected` to all 3 options and then only use ternary operator. So he may be out of concept. @mplungjan

Comment: its not working, Its showing > in left side of the SSgt name.

Comment: @Sid I missed the `echo` check it now.

Comment: `<?=` vs `<?PHP echo`  - any difference?

Comment: @mplungjan not at all. I just applied my practice... Ty for the edit.

Comment: Glad it helped @Sid, consider marking it as answer.